# Spring config for deployment on google app engine flex connecting to cloud sql

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I know there is a lot of issues like that in here but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.
I'm trying to find a way to make that project working on google app engine flex connecting to cloud sql in the same app engine project.

For that I use the code from [git](https://github.com/hellokoding/registration-login-spring-xml-maven-jsp-mysql)
I have the 3 files where to set the config: pom.xml, app.yaml, application.properties

I tried to add properties and dependencies to my pom.xml as said [on google](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql)

```
<properties>
    <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>project:region:instance</INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
    <user>myUser</user>
    <password>myPassword</password>
    <database>accounts</database>
    <sqlURL>jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&amp;user=${user}&amp;password=${password}&amp;useSSL=false</sqlURL>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I have my application.properties that contain value for the spring data-source (urls with IP and port works fine locally)

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://google/myDatabase?cloudSqlInstance=project:region:instance=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
#jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/myDatabase?    useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
#jdbc.url=mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project:region:instance;dbname=myDatabase
jdbc.username=myUser
jdbc.password=myPassword
```

I tried different url as you can see.

I also tried to add some lines in my app.yaml

```
resources:
  memory_gb: 2.3

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
```

or these

```
env_variables:
  MYSQL_DNS: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/project:region:instance;dbname=myDatabase
  MYSQL_USER: myUser
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: myPassword
```

or both.

I run out of idea. anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Spring Cloud GCP? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp. It has support for Cloud SQL and even a sample app with it.

Comment: Please share the error you get, otherwise it's hard to understand what is failing and what we should look for?

Comment: In case you don't do that already, if you set environment variables don't forget to read them as indicated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#Java_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables).